# Camel ZipAggregator stuck after camelLock

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to zip all txt files in one folder using Apache Camel 2.17.1. So, I define my route like this :

```
from("file:C:\\CamelFolder\\incoming?antInclude=*.txt").
    aggregate(new ZipAggregationStrategy()).constant(true).completionFromBatchConsumer().
    eagerCheckCompletion().setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, constant("report.zip")).to("file:C:\\CamelFolder\\outgoing");
```

After that I testing it by putting a.txt and abcd.txt into the incoming folder.
However, I noticed that a.txt has been processed, but abcd.txt has an abcd.txt.camelLock. In the outgoing, the report.zip is not created.

Is there anything I missed here?

From Tracer only this 2 lines added :

```
2016-05-30 17:12:26.437  INFO 7804 --- [lder%5Cincoming] o.a.camel.processor.interceptor.Tracer   : ID-7SGLPB02WTJY-57457-1464599544529-0-2 >>> (route1) from(file://C:%5CCamelFolder%5Cincoming?antInclude=*.txt) --> aggregate[true] <<< Pattern:InOnly, Headers:{breadcrumbId=ID-7SGLPB02WTJY-57457-1464599544529-0-1, CamelFileAbsolute=true, CamelFileAbsolutePath=C:\CamelFolder\incoming\a.txt, CamelFileLastModified=1464332583589, CamelFileLength=0, CamelFileName=a.txt, CamelFileNameConsumed=a.txt, CamelFileNameOnly=a.txt, CamelFileParent=C:\CamelFolder\incoming, CamelFilePath=C:\CamelFolder\incoming\a.txt, CamelFileRelativePath=a.txt}, BodyType:org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile, Body:[Body is file based: GenericFile[C:\CamelFolder\incoming\a.txt]]

2016-05-30 17:12:26.476  INFO 7804 --- [lder%5Cincoming] o.a.camel.processor.interceptor.Tracer   : ID-7SGLPB02WTJY-57457-1464599544529-0-5 >>> (route1) from(file://C:%5CCamelFolder%5Cincoming?antInclude=*.txt) --> aggregate[true] <<< Pattern:InOnly, Headers:{breadcrumbId=ID-7SGLPB02WTJY-57457-1464599544529-0-4, CamelFileAbsolute=true, CamelFileAbsolutePath=C:\CamelFolder\incoming\abcd.txt, CamelFileLastModified=1464593460240, CamelFileLength=0, CamelFileName=abcd.txt, CamelFileNameConsumed=abcd.txt, CamelFileNameOnly=abcd.txt, CamelFileParent=C:\CamelFolder\incoming, CamelFilePath=C:\CamelFolder\incoming\abcd.txt, CamelFileRelativePath=abcd.txt}, BodyType:org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile, Body:[Body is file based: GenericFile[C:\CamelFolder\incoming\abcd.txt]]
```

Update :Just noticed that if file size >0 bytes, it will zip correctly. However the system must support 0 bytes file.

Comment: Can you turn Camel debug on to see what exactly is going on?

Comment: If DEBUG didn't reveal anything then yes by all means try logging in TRACE level. However, just looking at your updated question, it does seem like a Camel bug. Can you possibly create a little unit test to reproduce the problem and commit it somewhere like github? This would help a lot to get it fixed.

Comment: Hi Ramin, I found the cause of the issue ( because 1 of the file is 0 bytes ). However still finding out  on how to overcome this issue ( my system allows zero size file ) .

Comment: You can filter those zero bytes files using the Filter EIP before the aggregator.

Comment: I logged a ticket about the zero file issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10007